# Python: Iterate through a list that refers to other lists

Tags: python, list

This isn't a list of lists, didn't know the proper way to ask this.

I have a list of variables and each one is a list, I am trying to get the variable from the list.

```
>>> print sortedList
['group0', 'group1', 'group2', 'group3', 'group4', 'group5', 'group6', 'group7', 'group8', 'group9', 'group10', 'group11', 'group12']
>>> print group0
['abc']
>>> print group2
['combine', 'id']
```

my loop fails to do what I want

```
for group in sortedList:
    for job in group:
        print job
g
r
o
u
p
0
....
```

The number of group lists varies so I don't know a good way to iterate through them except for getting a list of them

This is how I get sortedList:

```
group_re = re.compile('(group)(\d+)', re.I)
totalVars = vars().keys()
myList = [ s for s in totalVars if group_re.match(s)]
sortedList = sorted(myList, key=lambda x: (len (x), x))
```

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?  Why not just use a single list called `group` and access the individual sublists as `group[0]`, `group[1]`, etc.?

Comment: Or preferably store your groups as keys in a dictionary.

Comment: Your `sortedList` is a list of strings, not a list of variables.

Comment: Where do the group0, group1, etc. variables come from?

Comment: In your example, `group0` and `group2` are in the iterpreter's local namespace... I assume you did something like `group0 = [ 'abc']` but didn't show us that part. You have a list of variable names and you want to reference those variables. So, the question is, where are those variables defined and how did they get there in the first place? It makes a difference on how the problem is solved.

Comment: They are from a file that I import `from dependencies_groups import *`
`group0 = ['abc']`

`group2 = ['combine', 'id']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your example, you have variables defined in the interpreter's local namespace and you want to reference by names in another list. You can do that using the `locals()` function, like so:

```
for group in sortedList:
    for job in locals()[group]:
        print job
```

If these variables are defined at the module level, you'd use `globals()[group]` instead.

From your updated information, the variables are in the `dependencies_groups` namespace, but since you did `from dependencies_groups import *`, they are also in your module's globals and should be referenced as `globals()[group]`. You could also grab them from the other module with a different function:

```
import dependencies_groups
for group in sortedList:
    for job in getattr(dependencies_groups, group):
        print job
```

Some find this last method preferable because its more clear where the groups came from.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to access the variables group0, group1, etc. using a list of strings "group0", "group1", etc..  You need to somehow map those strings to the lists.  The common way of doing this would be to format your group lists not as variables but as dict entries.

Here is a working example:

```
groups = {
    "group0": ['abc'],
    "group1": ['combine', 'id']
}

sortedList = [ "group0", "group1", "group2" ]

for name in sortedList:
    group = groups.get(name)
    if group:
        print "Executing jobs from {0}...".format(name)
        for job in group:
            print "\tJob {0}".format(job)
    else:
        print "{0} not found!".format(name)
```

repl.it link: http://repl.it/eT1

Comment: The global and local namespaces are dicts, so even though its common to stick them in a dict, you don't have to.

Comment: @tdelaney True but if the OP has control over how group0, etc. are defined it would be cleaner and more maintainable to just move them to a dedicated dict.